# Java: Replace Text with Image Mid-String and align with Word Wrapping

Tags: java, string, replace, bufferedimage, word-wrap

I am still a bit new to Java programming so sorry for the huge dump of text. I greatly appreciate you taking the time to read over my current problem!

I am working on software to help speed up the process of board game design using Java Swing. It takes a CSV file of cards for a game, lets you build a dummy card by placing where each column will render on the card and then automatically generating all of the cards in the CSV from these positions.

Many card games have symbols that represent something in the game and I want to be able to insert them in the middle of strings. I can currently replace an entire string with a symbol; as it checks if the `string == a known rule`, draw the symbol instead. However, I don't know how I would go about searching through a string for a specific set of characters. If it finds them, delete them from the string and then draw the corresponding symbol in it's place. A great example can be seen with the mana symbols on magic cards: https://cdn0.vox-cdn.com/uploads/chorus_asset/file/8039357/C0cIVZ5.png

So the string could be: `Gain 1 {GOLD} at the start of each tun.`
And it would need to replace `{GOLD}` with the picture of gold using the Rule class that contains the string to find and a buffered image to replace it with.

I would like this to work without using a hard limit on the size of the symbol, but that is not a hard requirement. The best solution would scale the symbol so it's height was the same of the text.

This method takes a buffered image (a card with no text) and overlays the text on top of the card.

```
//Will modify the buffered image with the placeables
static public BufferedImage buildCard(BufferedImage start, int whichCardID) {
    //Copy so we don't lose our template
    BufferedImage ni = deepCopy(start); //ni = new image

    //The headers of the document
    String[] headers = MainWindow.loadedCards.get(0);

    //For each placeable, write down it's text
    for(int i=0; i<headers.length; i++) {
        //get current header
        String currentHeader = headers[i];

        //The Text
        String theText = MainWindow.loadedCards.get(whichCardID)[i];

        //The Settings
        PlaceableSettings theSettings = MainWindow.placeableSettings.get(currentHeader);

        //Make the change to the image
        //ni = writeToImage(ni, theText, theSettings);

        ///////New below
        boolean foundRule = false;

        //see if we have a rule to draw a graphic instead
        for(RuleMaster.Rule r : RuleMaster.rules) {
            if(r.keyword.equals(theText)) {
                //there is a rule for this!
                ni = drawRuleToImage(ni, r, theSettings);
                foundRule = true; //so we don't draw the current text
            }
        }
        //No rules for this

        //Make the change to the image if there are no rules
        if(foundRule == false)
            ni = writeToImage(ni, theText, theSettings);
    }
    return ni;
}

//Takes a buffered image and writes text into it at the location given
static public BufferedImage writeToImage(BufferedImage old, String text, PlaceableSettings setts) {
    //make new blank graphics
    BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(old.getWidth(), old.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    Graphics2D g2d = bi.createGraphics();

    //write old image to it
    g2d.drawImage(old, 0, 0, null); //null was set to "this" when this was not static | Note ion case this breaks

    //write text on it
    g2d.setPaint(setts.getColor());
    g2d.setFont(setts.getFont());

    //Setup word wrap
    FontMetrics fm = g2d.getFontMetrics(setts.getFont());
    //    int rightSideBuffer = bi.getWidth() - 10;
    //Rectangle2D rect = fm.getStringBounds(text, setts.getX(), rightSideBuffer, g2d); // try just -'ing the x slot from the width below
    Rectangle2D rect = fm.getStringBounds(text, g2d); //this gets you the bounds for the entire image, need to remove space for x,y position


    //TODO: Problem: this is always length 1
    //Solution! No auto wrap, let the person define it as a setting
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<String> textList=StringUtils.wrap(text, fm, setts.getPixelsTillWrap() ); //width counted in # of characters

    //g2d.drawString(text, setts.getX(), setts.getY()); //old draw with no wrap



    for(int i=0; i< textList.size(); i++) {
        g2d.drawString(textList.get(i), setts.getX(), setts.getY() + ( i*(setts.getFont().getSize() + 2/*Buffer*/)));
    }

    //!!DEBUG
    if(EntryPoint.DEBUG) {
        Random r = new Random();
        g2d.setPaint(Color.RED);
        g2d.drawString(Integer.toString(textList.size()), 100, 50+r.nextInt(250));
        g2d.setPaint(Color.GREEN);
        g2d.drawString(Double.toString(rect.getWidth()), 200, 50+r.nextInt(250));
        g2d.setPaint(Color.PINK);
        //g2d.drawString(Integer.toString(( ((int) rect.getWidth()) - setts.getX())), 100, 250+r.nextInt(100));

    }

    //cleanup
    g2d.dispose();

    return bi;
}

//Takes a buffered image and draws an image on it at the location given
static public BufferedImage drawRuleToImage(BufferedImage old, RuleMaster.Rule rule, PlaceableSettings theSettings) {
    //make new blank graphics
    BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(old.getWidth(), old.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    Graphics2D g2d = bi.createGraphics();

    //write old image to it
    g2d.drawImage(old, 0, 0, null); //null was set to "this" when this was not static | Note ion case this breaks

    g2d.drawImage(rule.image, theSettings.getX(), theSettings.getY(), null);

    //cleanup
    g2d.dispose();

    //System.exit(1);

    return bi;
}
```

Each Rule just contains the string to replace and the image to replace it with.

```
static public class Rule{
    //Text to look for
    String keyword;
    //image to replace it with
    BufferedImage image;

    public Rule (String key, BufferedImage img) {
        keyword = key;
        image = img;
    }
}
```

I am attempting to design this as a tool for many people to use, so the text should be able to match whatever the user adds; though my current process has been to use strings such as "{M}" and that could be a standard.

Another big hurdle in this is that the text can wrap on the cards, which means that the strings and image need to wrap together in provided bounds.

Edit 1:
Had some thoughts and am going to try this approach. Still see a possible issue with the bounds when getting the 'next' half of the string drawn; but I believe this may work.

```
//If found a rule mid text:

            //Split string in 2 at the rule match: strings 'start', and 'next'
            //Calculate x and y for symbol
            //x is the # of characters in ('start' % the word wrap width) +1 as the symbol is the next character, then multiply that by the character size of the font
            //y is the integer of dividing the # of characters in 'start' by word wrap width multiplied by the font height
            //Draw Start of String
            //Draw symbol

            //next x = sym.x + sym width //TODO next (x,y) math
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem by warping ahead of time based on the text size. By using a known size of the image, it could be know ahead of time to get the wrap done right.

Then I looped through each line. I looked did a split in the string on the text that would be replaced. I them drew the first part of the string as normal. Calculated the width of the string using `int pixelWidth = ni.getGraphics().getFontMetrics().stringWidth(splitString[j]);`. Then drew the image at the same Y, but added the width of the previous string to the X. Then added the current width of the image to the X and continued looping; drawing images and strings as needed.